# List of all android callback methods

Tags: android, callback

Is there any list of all android callback methods anywhere? I want all different kinds of android callback methods with their type. For example "onClick" which is a GUI related callback. I need all callbacks of all types such as sensor related callbacks and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at lifecycle callback methods such as onCreate and onDestroy and handlers such as onTextChanged, onClick, onTouch and so on.

Android developers doc is your best friend to know them all, and related layouts and views, best practices, etc.